# How to delete a cheat score in google play games Leaderboard?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard, anti-cheat

i have a fake score in my leaderboard, exists a way to delete it? I only can see how to delete the entire leaderboard, but i just want to delete one score...

how can this be achieved?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can remove a specific entry manually. I would try enabling tamper protection if it isn't already:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

> Hiding leaderboard scores
>
> Play Game services provides a leaderboard tamper protection feature
>   that checks for suspected tampered scores and hides them
>   automatically. This feature is available for Android games only.
>
> ...
>
> 1) In the Google Play Developer Console, open the Games services tab,
>   then select your game from the list. 
>   2) Open the Leaderboards tab,
>   then select the leaderboard instance for which you want to enable
>   tamper protection. 
>   3) Turn the Enable leaderboard tamper protection
>   option to ON. 
>   4) Click Save and continue. 
>   5) Publish your game.
>
> Once tamper protection is enabled for a leaderboard in the Google Play
>   Developer Console, it may take up to 24 hours before this feature
>   takes effect. Scores submitted before you enabled tamper protection
>   are not retroactively hidden.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think its possible to delete those value,But you can avoid those scores get posted again in the LeaderBoard. if You are submitting from the Player Prefs or Xml data,Remember those things can be changeable by the Phone that are Rooted . So try to Encrypt the Data while storing the Data and do decrypt to retrieve it.

Thats it Man.

Comment: ummmm i can't believe it. must be a way to solve this